# XCode 4: Create iPad Version using autosizing masks

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, interface-builder, xcode4

I've just upgraded to XCode 4 Gold and I can't find a way to automatically create the iPad view from an iPhone view (or viceversa).

To be clear, the feature I am looking is the same as in the Interface Builder of XCode 3, there is an option "Create iPhone/iPod touch version using autosizing masks" when you're working on an iPad View, and "Create iPad version using autosizing masks" on iPhone/iPod Touch.

If anybody know if this is possible...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Xcode 4 is still under NDA and cannot be discussed publicly. I would suggest going to https://devforums.apple.com/community/xcode4 and asking the question.

Comment: Now that its publicly released, I would like to know the answer to this as well. Will search.

Comment: Did anyone find the answer for this?

Comment: I've reported this to Apple as an Enhancement. So let's hope that they here our prayers....

Comment: Apple is aware of this bug and apparently they are working on it.

Answer (score 3):

There is still a way to convert xibs to iPad.  It is just hard to find:

1. Select the project in the navigator, then right-click the target and make sure it is set to iPhone -- if set to Universal this process will not work.  (You can set it back to universal afterwards)
2. Right click the target and then select Duplicate.
3. Choose to Duplicate and Transition to iPad. A group called "Resources-iPad" will be added to your project and will contain the iPad-converted xibs.

Comment: I know this works but I don't it's the proper way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: It is the only way that I've found.  Definitely post here if you find another!